# how i may get name of all namespaces (@kubernetes/client-node)

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubectl

I work with API kuberneteswith (library is @kubernetes/client-node).
I can to get a list of pods of specigic namespace, but i don`t understand to get a list of name all namespaces
How i may code with @kubernetes/client-node?

Comment: Can you please share the code, how you are accessing all the pods inside a namespace. It will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the corev1 API, it's `listNamespace`.

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespace().then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

Comment: @coderanger i need to return all the active jobs(pods, deployments and services) (maybe using kubeconfig file inside ./kube folder). 
I tried to change loadFromDefault to loadFromFile('./path/file.yaml') but it is not working, can you please suggest anything?

Comment: @shivam Don't ask unrelated questions in comments.

Comment: I apologize, I created a question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550814/unable-to-get-all-the-jobs-inside-a-cluster-using-kubernetes-client-node#68550923