# Unable to get all the jobs inside a cluster using @kubernetes/client-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes

I am using `@kubernetes/client-node` to access Kubernetes server API. I can get all the Pods from default using:

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespace().then((res) => {  // or using listAllNamespacedPods
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

and the body of the response from the above code looks like this:

[image: Response From loadFromDefault]

but when I am using `kc.loadFromFile('pathToKubeConfigFile')`, it is unable to read it (the `config.yaml` which is saved inside `.kube` folder).
I have checked all the paths to certificates and keys files inside this file and they are correct.

```
import { KubeConfig, CoreV1Api } from '@kubernetes/client-node';

const kc = new KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromFile('./config/k8sConfig.yaml');

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listPodForAllNamespaces().then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

and I need to return all the active Kubernetes Jobs (or the pods for that). Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting. Please update your question with the error message so that we can better understand the issue an be able to help you

Comment: Could you please provide the error message as @dstrants mentioned ?  It'll allow to further investigate this issue.
Additionally, can you try to use an absolute path in the `loadFromFile()`?

Comment: The problem has been solved, in the k8Config.yaml file the path to client certificate was wrong. I changed it to right path and it worked.

Comment: @shivam, I am getting this error: "TypeError: k8sApi.listNamespace is not a function". I have the exact code like you. Can you guide me on what will be the issue? Is it something related to the version I installed? or something else!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem has already been resolved in the comments section, I decided to provide a Community Wiki answer just for better visibility to other community members. I would also like to describe how to return all active Kubernetes Jobs using the [Javascript Kubernetes Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript#javascript-kubernetes-client-information)

###### Using the loadFromFile() method.

When using the `loadFromFile()` method, it's important to make sure that the `kubeconfig` file is correct. In case the `kubeconfig` file is invalid, we may get various error messages such as:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.kube/confi'
```

or

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
```

The exact error message depends on what is incorrect in the `kubeconfig` file.

###### List all/active Kubernetes Jobs.

To list all Kubernetes Jobs, we can use the [listJobForAllNamespaces()](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/1d5d4660f99807e3d3b02dd0984d0b980f279ff9/src/gen/api/batchV1Api.ts#L950) method.

I've created the `listAllJobs.js` script to demonstrate how it works:

```
$ cat listAllJobs.js
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node')
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig()
kc.loadFromFile('.kube/config')

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.BatchV1Api);

k8sApi.listJobForAllNamespaces().then((res) => {
    res.body.items.forEach(job => console.log(job.metadata.name));
});


$ kubectl get jobs
NAME    COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job-1   0/1           3s         3s
job-2   1/1           10s        48m
job-3   1/1           10s        48m 

$ node listAllJobs.js
job-1
job-2
job-3
```

To list only active Jobs, we need to slightly modify the `res.body.items.forEach(job => console.log(job.metadata.name));` line to check if the Job is active:

```
$ cat listActiveJobs.js
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node')
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig()
kc.loadFromFile('.kube/config')

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.BatchV1Api);

k8sApi.listJobForAllNamespaces().then((res) => {
    res.body.items.forEach(job => job.status.active >= 1 && console.log(job.metadata.name));
});


$ kubectl get jobs
NAME    COMPLETIONS   
job-1   0/1           
job-2   1/1           
job-3   1/1          

$ node listActiveJobs.js 
job-1
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, how can I create a job using nodejs? Using post request?

Comment: You can use the [createNamespacedJob()](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/1d5d4660f99807e3d3b02dd0984d0b980f279ff9/src/gen/api/batchV1Api.ts#L198) method. It works pretty similar as the `createNamespacedIngress()` described in this [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/ingress.js).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the Kube config file location instead of any YAML file

```
const { KubeConfig } = require('kubernetes-client')
const kubeconfig = new KubeConfig()
kubeconfig.loadFromFile('~/some/path')
const Request = require('kubernetes-client/backends/request')

const backend = new Request({ kubeconfig })
const client = new Client({ backend, version: '1.13' })
```

https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client#initializing

However if you are planning to run the POD or container on K8s cluster you can also use : `kc.loadFromCluster();`

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/in-cluster.js

If you want to pass any YAML and apply those changes to cluster you can use the

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/yaml-example.js

Comment: I need to give path of config file(which is inside .kube folder) here: kubeconfig.loadFromFile('~/some/path'), right?

Comment: if you are planning to run the code inside pod or container on K8s cluster you can also use : kc.loadFromCluster(); in that case no need to give kubeconfig file it will auto manage it

Comment: i getting this Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt'"

Comment: share your code are you using this method for auth ?